# python-regex change any word I want

Tags: python, regex

thanks to everyone's help i got to this step but I have a few new problems that I hope someone can help me with,I found the following you words and want to replace them with another word but this code only works for the first word

```
import Re
text = 'Suddenly you said goodbye, even though I was passionately in love with you, I hope you stay lonely and live for a hundred years'
def replace(text,key,value,NumberL):
    matches = list(re.finditer(key,text,re.I))
    for i in NumberL:
        newT = matches[i-1]
        text = text[:newT.start(0)] + value + text[newT.end(0):]
    print(text)
replace(text,'you','Cleis',[2,3])
```

result:  Suddenly you said goodbye, even though I was passionately in love with Cleis, I ''hopCleisou'' stay lonely and live for a hundred years.

I edited and highlighted the error word.

Can someone give me a solution to this problem?

Comment: You should not use this with `re.finditer`, use `re.sub`. The problem is that your offset is wrong after you modify the input text.

Comment: Does `NumberL` stand for occurrence numbers?

Comment: `NumberL` is the number of words I found in text

Comment: So you want to replace the second and third `you` in the string if `NumberL` is `[2,3]`?

Comment: yes and I think re.sub and re.replace are not very different

Comment: There is no `re.replace`

Comment: yes i tried both but can't match the position of the word to be replaced but will replace all the words 'You'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```py
import re

def repl(m, value, counter, NumberL):
    counter.i += 1
    if counter.i in NumberL:
        return value
    return m.group()

def replace(text,key,value,NumberL):
    counter = lambda x: None
    counter.i = 0
    return re.sub(rf"(?!\B\w){re.escape(key)}(?<!\w\B)", lambda m: repl(m, value, counter, NumberL), text)
    
text = 'Suddenly you said goodbye, even though I was passionately in love with you, I hope you stay lonely and live for a hundred years'
print(replace(text,'you','Cleis',[2,3]))
```

Output:

```
Suddenly you said goodbye, even though I was passionately in love with Cleis, I hope Cleis stay lonely and live for a hundred years
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/ZcbCQC).

*Details*:

- `counter = lambda x: None` sets up a counter object and `counter.i = 0` sets the `i` property to `0`
- `re.sub(rf"(?!\B\w){re.escape(key)}(?<!\w\B)", lambda m: repl(m, value, counter, NumberL), text)` finds all occurrences of `key` that is searched as a whole word (accounting for any special chars in the `key`) and replaces it with the `repl` function
- In the `repl` function, the `counter.i` is incremented and if the found match is in `NumberL`, the replacement takes place, else, the found match is put back.